# How to plot one graph of ROC curve for 4 separate ML model located in different python notebooks

Tags: machine-learning, python, roc

if we have 4 different notebooks for different ML model results .. and we have to plot one ROC curve graph which shows the ROc of all 4 models. how can we do this

this is my code in every notebook to plot roc

```
import sklearn.metrics as metrics
# calculate the fpr and tpr for all thresholds of the classification

fpr, tpr, threshold = metrics.roc_curve(y_true1, y_pred1)
roc_auc = metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)

# method I: plt

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic')
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, 'b', label = 'AUC = %0.2f' % roc_auc)
plt.legend(loc = 'lower right')
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1],'r--')
plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.ylim([0, 1])
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Write all of the points in the ROC curve to a data CVS file, one for each notebook. One column gives the true positive rate (y-axis), while another column gives the false positive rate. A third column should uniquely identify the notebook of origin for this data frame and will be used later for labeling the graph.
2. Read your CSV files to data frames in a new script, perhaps in a fifth notebook.
3. Combine those data frames. `pd.concat` is likely to be your friend.
4. Plot your four curves, coloring according to the notebook of origin.

Comment: how to print all point in ROC curve to csv file

Comment: `pd.to_csv` will do the trick.

Comment: but in current code which variable to save that's unclear to me

Comment: i am confused how to get all points of roc curve

Comment: @user12 What’s in your first `plt.plot` line?

Comment: import pandas as pd 
pd.DataFrame(tpr).to_csv("C:/ROC.csv")
pd.DataFrame(fpr).to_csv("C:/ROC1.csv") is it correct way

Comment: I would do one data frame with one column for TPR and another for FPR, so something more like `pd.DataFrame({“tpr”: tpr, “fpr”: fpr}).to_csv(“C:/roc1.csv”)`. I’m going from memory and didn’t run that line, so you might have to tweak the exact syntax, but that is the gist.